# Understanding setting h = 0 in derivation of simple transport PDE

Tags: partial-differential-equations

In deriving the simple transport PDE,

[image]

Strauss "Introduction to Partial Differentials" shows

[image]

however, **why is setting $h = 0$ necessary?**

I provide my attempt at the derivation below, and I don't see where $h = 0$ is required to get equation (1).

$$
\begin{aligned}
\frac{d}{db} \int_0^b u(x,t)dx &= \frac{d}{db} \int_{ch}^{b+ch} u(x, t+h)dx \\\\
\frac{d}{db} \left[U(b, t) - U(0, t) \right] &= \frac{d}{db} \left[ U(b+ch, t+h) - U(ch, t+h) \right] && \text{FTC} \\\\
u(b, t) &= u(b+ch, t+h) && \text{Keep upper lims of integrals because variable first argument to functions } U(\cdot) \\\\
\frac{d}{dh}[u(b, t)] &= \frac{d}{dh}[u(b+ch, t+h)] && \text{Differentiating w.r.t } h \\\\
0 &= \frac{\partial u}{\partial x} \frac{\partial x}{\partial h} + \frac{\partial u}{\partial t} \frac{\partial t}{\partial h} && \text{Multivariable chain rule} \\\\
0 &= u_x \frac{\partial}{\partial h}[b + ch] + u_t \frac{\partial}{\partial h}[t + h] \\\\
0 &= u_x c + u_t 1 \\\\
0 &= u_t + c u_x && \text{Rearranged}
\end{aligned}
$$